# Python SonarQube Integration with nosetests and coverage not shown cover code

Tags: python, sonarqube, code-coverage, nose

I have created sample project (PyCharm+Mac) to integrate SonarQube into python using nosetests and coverage :

**src/Sample.py**

```
import sys


def fact(n):
    """
    Factorial function

    :arg n: Number
    :returns: factorial of n

    """
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n - 1)


def main(n):
    res = fact(n)
    print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__' and len(sys.argv) > 1:
        main(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

**test/SampleTest.py**

```
import unittest
from src.Sample import fact


class TestFactorial(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Our basic test class
    """

    def test_fact1(self):
        """
        The actual test.
        Any method which starts with ``test_`` will considered as a test case.
        """
        res = fact(0)
        self.assertEqual(res, 1)

    def test_fac2(self):
        """
         The actual test.
         Any method which starts with ``test_`` will considered as a test case.
        """
        res = fact(5)
        self.assertEqual(res, 120)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**sonar-project.properties**

```
sonar.projectKey=SonarQubeSample
sonar.projectName=Sonar Qube Sample
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=test
sonar.language=py
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=nosetests.xml
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=coverage.xml
sonar.python.coveragePlugin=cobertura
```

Below command will create **nosetests.xml** file successfully :

```
nosetests --with-xunit ./test/SampleTest.py
```

When i run below command :

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=src --cover-inclusive --cover-xml
```

It will given below result :

```
Name              Stmts   Miss  Cover
-------------------------------------
src/Sample.py        10      6    40%
src/__init__.py       0      0   100%
-------------------------------------
TOTAL                10      6    40%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.011s

OK
```

Why fact function code not shown cover into SonarQube my project as below after running `sonar-scanner` command?

[image]

Comment: Because you're only testing `fact`, which *isn't* 100% of the code in that file? Why did you think you'd get more?

Comment: When i check coverage.xml it will shown hits to fact code.

Answer (score 3):

You should always try to make one test fail to be sure that your command tests something. The following command does not execute any tests:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=src --cover-inclusive --cover-xml
```

One solution is to add `test/*Test.py` at the end.
To generate `nosetests.xml` and `coverage.xml` with only one command, you can execute:

```
nosetests --with-xunit --with-coverage --cover-package=src --cover-inclusive --cover-xml test/*Test.py
```

Note: You need to create a `test/__init__.py` file (even empty), so the file path in `nosetests.xml` can be resolved.

Note: You need at least SonarPython version 1.9 to parse `coverage.xml`

Comment: I have try as you suggest and it will cover 70% now but when change my *Test.py file and run command again to check cover then it will shown 70% not change cover percentage as per my test cases.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: so 1.9 version is required in order for unit test coverage to show up in sonar(python) ?